# Laravel and DOMPDF - Set content margins

Tags: html, css, laravel-5, dompdf

I have a controller function that generates a PDF from a view. I want to print a page with a background and the content inside the white section of the background. I have the measures in points and works perfect on first page, but I have 2 issues:

- On the second page the content appears without margins, just in the top of the page.
- The background only prints half of his size on the second page (where the content finishes).

This is the HTML:

```
   <div class="contenedor">
      <div class="cuerpo">
        <h3 style="margin: 20px 0;">Candidatos contratados a día {{ Date('d/m/Y') }}</h3>
        <table class="table" style="border: 0;">
          <thead>
            <tr style="text-transform: uppercase;">
              <th width="40%" style="background-color: #DBDBDB;">Candidato</th>
              <th width="40%" style="background-color: #F1F1F1;">Posto</th>
              <th width="20%" style="background-color: #F1F1F1;">Tipo</th>
              <th width="5%" style="background-color: #F1F1F1;">Horas</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach($clientes as $cliente)
              <tr>
                <td width="40%" style="background-color: #EBEDED;" data-title="Candidato">{{ $cliente->apellidos }}, {{ $cliente->nombre }}</td>
                <td width="40%"  data-title="Posto">{{ $cliente->puesto }}</td>
                <td width="10%" data-title="Tipo">{{ $cliente->tipo }}</td>
                <td width="10%" data-title="Horas">{{ $cliente->horas_semanales }}</td>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is the CSS code

```
  @page {
    margin: 0;
  }
  *{
    color: #111;
  }
  body {
    font-size: 11pt;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .contenedor{
    background-image: url('{{ URL::asset('images/fondo-imprimir.jpg') }}');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  .background{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 595.276pt;
    height: 841.89pt;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .background img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .cuerpo{
    page-break-after: auto;
    max-width: 484.725pt;
    max-height: 635.275pt;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: 107.402pt 56.693pt 99.213pt 53.858pt;
  }
  tr  { page-break-before: auto; max-height: 40pt; }
  td{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
  }
  #duracion, #completado{ display: none; }
```

As you can see, I set page and body margins and paddings to 0 In order to set the background in all the paper, and the `.cuerpo` div with margins `margin: 107.402pt 56.693pt 99.213pt 53.858pt;` set in the blank section of the background. First page works almost perfect, second do not follows this rules.

Answer (score 0):

Elements that are paged do not duplicate their margin across pages ([see issue #640](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/640)). What you would want to do instead is set the page margin to 0 and pad the body.

Assuming your `.cuerpo` div has the correct spacing you might try the following:

```
  @page {
    margin: 0;
  }
  *{
    color: #111;
  }
  body {
    font-size: 11pt;
    padding: 107.402pt 56.693pt 99.213pt 53.858pt;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .contenedor{
    background-image: url('{{ URL::asset('images/fondo-imprimir.jpg') }}');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  .background{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 595.276pt;
    height: 841.89pt;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .background img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .cuerpo{
    page-break-after: auto;
    max-width: 484.725pt;
    max-height: 635.275pt;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  tr  { page-break-before: auto; max-height: 40pt; }
  td{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
  }
  #duracion, #completado{ display: none; }
```

As for the half-page issue, that may be an issue with how the height of the body is being determined (depending on your version of dompdf). Add info regarding your version of dompdf and I'll update this answer.